# Disable TCP-Offloading {completely, generically and easily}

Tags: linux, networking, debian, tcp-offload-engine

I want to disable *tcp-offloading* (TOE) on my Debian servers. I would use something like:

```bash
ethtool -K …
```

I have some wishes, though: is it possible to integrate it cleanly into Debian?

This reads: no `rc.local`, I would also like to avoid pseudo-rc-scripting.

I would guess, it's installing `ethtool` and using the pre-up.d/hook which deconfigures TOE using options from `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I would like to deconfigure all my (future) servers in a generic fashion using FAI (since FAI is already in place - and wanted!).

What about toe-options that are not supported on some hardware? Will networking fail if a non-existing-option should be disabled? I guess it should be robust not to do so, but this does not seem to be my wanted solution, either.

It clutters the config very much, since atm there are 11 options! Using multiple NICs this smells error-prone to me.

Isn't there a more generic solution? I have a sysctl in mind, but did not find one yet. My wish was:

```bash
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/core/enable_tcp_offloading
```

**PS**: I'm quite surprised to find my "newer hardware" to have TOE enabled by default, because of [this](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/toe).

Comment: I would like to point out that while the arguments agaist TOE are true, it's mostly Tin-Foil hat types who don't have to live with realistic constrains (where any acceleration is usually helpful). There are plenty of edge cases where TOE should be disabled, but it's not common and doesn't merit the effort to make disabling it "generic and easy".

Comment: @Chris S: Right, but I did not mind TOE until it messed up. And it really sums up lately that network issues boil down to "disable TOE". So I want it! :D I could live with the ethtool-Method, but hope for someone knowing "the knob"....

Comment: @Michuelnik yeah - if it's working I would let it run, but if it's acting up and causing problems for you that's a good reason to disable it.  You *may* want to leave some parts of the offload engine active though if Linux allows it: Offloading checksums for example (hard to screw up CRC32, and the cards do it in hardware which is faster and saves you a few CPU cycles per packet which can add up in high-traffic networks)

Comment: @voretaq7: Good point! Thought about it shortly, whether I should distinguish between usable and miserable options. But I needed a quite quick solution without studying TOE too long, especially since the TOE stuff seems soo vendor specific that it's knowledge thats ageing too fast to invest time into it. Is TX-chksum-offloading the origin why my wireshark complains about wrong chksums?

Comment: I have to say the features you're disabling are not TOE. TOE is a full TCP offload engine. You're disabling just checksum offload, send segmentation offload and receive reassembly offload. None of those features are TOE. Linux does not support TOE: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/toe

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On Debian, the `ethtool` package now provides an `if-up.d` script that implements options for offloading (and other `ethtool` settings).

You just have to install this package and add lines like these to the interface in`/etc/network/interfaces`.

```bash
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.3.1/255.255.248.0
    gateway 10.0.2.10
    offload-tx  off
    offload-sg  off
    offload-tso off
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: This is documented in /usr/share/doc/ethtool/README.Debian <https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/ethtool/-/blob/master/debian/README.Debian>.

Answer (score 8):

Eureka! Found "my" solution!

I'm simply placing my own *disable-toe* Script in */etc/network/if-up.d/* which disables tcp-offloading completely.

As bonus I've added an */etc/network/interfaces*-Option, that disables this.

```
#!/bin/bash

RUN=true
case "${IF_NO_TOE,,}" in
    no|off|false|disable|disabled)
        RUN=false
    ;;
esac

if [ "$MODE" = start -a "$RUN" = true ]; then
  TOE_OPTIONS="rx tx sg tso ufo gso gro lro rxvlan txvlan rxhash"
  for TOE_OPTION in $TOE_OPTIONS; do
    /sbin/ethtool --offload "$IFACE" "$TOE_OPTION" off &>/dev/null || true
  done
fi
```

Comment: "Eureka" doesn't have a "H" in it.

Comment: In my mother tongue, it has... ;-p

Comment: Debian(ish) specific (or at least requiring stuff that respects `if-up.d`), but pretty elegant - I like.

Comment: @voretaq7: Thanks! Still have to improve - handling bond devices and maybe other special cases.

Comment: You'd better use a `post-up for i in rx tx gso ; do ethtool -K $IFACE $i off; done` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @JB: Why? Want to disable it before the interfaces comes up and avoid any race condition at all. And where's the difference between a post-up section and a home-brewed interfaces-hook?

Comment: @Michuelnik: IMHO the post-up/pre-up integrates more cleanly with debian + configuration is in a single file. Beware: I experienced that in case of bonding/bridging the pre/post are only called on the interfaces that are actually brought up (not on the slaves, etc..)

Comment: @JB: actually I am doing this, I just provide some more commands for the network/interfaces. I still have to enable it for every interface.It's not that explicit, but more easy to be distributed and maintained among a lot of servers and enabled/disabled very easy without many pitfalls.
I think it's a lot more easy to add a "if_no_toe yes" to the config than to copy the toe-disabling-statement every time around. And updating a manually (likely very similar and likely not identical) written statement makes me shiver.

Comment: @Michuelnik Clean solution, I like it! But you're going a bit further than OP demand : `sg ufo gso gro lro rxvlan txvlan rxhash` options are **not related to TCP/TOE**.

Answer (score 3):

Off topic (sort of) but I ended up here when trying to figure out how to do the same thing for some RHEL6 servers. So if anyone is looking for the same thing for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora like distributions, you'll find the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/463111/).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a system that uses [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) (e.g. Ubuntu) to configure the network then you can use a [Netplan post-up script](https://netplan.io/faq#use-pre-up-post-up-etc-hook-scripts) to configure offloading. As mentioned in an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032153/how-to-execute-post-up-scripts-with-netplan) to another question.

You create a script in the following directory with a name prefixed by a number to indicate load order e.g. `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/40-offloading-config` - which is executable and owned by root. e.g. To switch off TCP Segment Offloading on eth0:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/ethtool -K eth0 tso off
```

Comment: This works great on Ubuntu Server 20.04, thanks!