# What problems can the use of TOE cause?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking, tcp-offload-engine

What problems can the use of TOE cause?

As known, TOE ([TCP offload engine](https://www.chelsio.com/nic/tcp-offload-engine/)) offloads the processing of TCP/IP stack from CPU to the NIC: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/toe

1. CPU has more free resources - so the user application runs faster
2. Also it increases throughput and reduces latency of the network application: http://www.epsglobal.com/downloads/Chelsio/Chelsio-Solarflare-TL-1.pdf

[image]

But why is it [sometimes recommended](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH197934) to turn off the TOE? [Disable TCP-Offloading {completely, generically and easily}](https://serverfault.com/questions/421995/disable-tcp-offloading-completely-generically-and-easily)

Why TOE can be so slow in some cases? https://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/nic-tuning/

> It has been reported that both TCP Segmentation Offloading (TSO) and
>   TCP Offload Engine **(TOE) on the Chelsio NIC radically hurt performance
>   on a WAN** (they do help reduce CPU load without affecting throughput on
>   a LAN). This is particularly true with a very fast CPU.

What problems can the use of TOE cause?

Comment: The [Support In Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine#Support_in_Linux) section of the Wikipedia article on TOE has a good summary of the drawbacks.